# how to make pg.PlotItem.removeItem() recognize PlotDataItems solely off name?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I have a function that adds PlotDataItem to a specific plot widget, however, if I try to use the removeItem function on the plot widget, it doesn't really do anything. I was seeking help on how I can make remove item work for this specific scenario? Any other tips you may recommend for optimization, readability, etc. are also greatly appreciated as I am still fairly new to PyQt and even Python itself. Thank you!

This function includes the removeItem() function.

```
def updateGraph(self):
        """Clears and updates graph to match the toggled checkboxes.
        """
        # self.graphWidget.clear()

        for checkboxNumber, checkbox in enumerate(
            self.scenarioWidget.findChildren(QtWidgets.QCheckBox)
        ):
            if checkbox.isChecked():
                peak = self._model.get_peak(checkboxNumber)
                duration = self._model.get_duration(checkboxNumber)
                self.drawLine(
                    name=checkbox.objectName(),
                    peak=peak,
                    color=2 * checkboxNumber,
                    duration=duration,
                )
            else:
                self.graphWidget.removeItem(pg.PlotDataItem(name=checkbox.objectName()))

        # TODO: Allow for removal of individual pg.PlotDataItems via self.graphWidget.removeItem()
```

This function is where the PlotDataItems are added to the plot widget.

```
def drawLine(self, name, peak, color, duration=100.0):
        """Graphs sinusoidal wave off given 'peak' and 'duration' predictions to model epidemic spread.

        Arguments:
            name {string} -- Name of scenario/curve
            peak {float} -- Predicted peak (%) of epidemic.
            color {float} -- Color of line to graph.

        Keyword Arguments:
            duration {float} -- Predicted duration of epidemic (in days). (default: {100.0})
        """
        X = np.arange(duration)
        y = peak * np.sin((np.pi / duration) * X)

        self.graphWidget.addItem(
            pg.PlotDataItem(X, y, name=name, pen=pg.mkPen(width=3, color=color))
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new object with `pg.PlotDataItem(name=checkbox.objectName())`, so it  will not be found as it's completely new.

Untested but should work:

```
for item in self.graphWidget.listDataItems():
    if item.name() == checkbox.objectName():
        self.graphWidget.removeItem(item)
```